# Extract every n-th year set in R

Tags: r, extract, crosstab

I have a 50-year data set in long format that has two variables for seven regional factors for each year.  I would like to create a summary table that lists the value of a a new variable (created by dividing variable 1 by variable 2 for each region for each year) every 10-years. (Basically, a summary data table in wide formate to accompany the annual graph produced in ggplot2).

I understand how to extract certain rows and columns from a data frame, and have found answers for every n-th element here in stack overflow.  However, I have been unable to figure out how to extract a set of 7 values (ie. one value for each region) every 10 years.

The below is an extract of my dataset - it would be repeated each year from 1961 to 2011. I would like to extract only 1961, 1971...2001, 2011.

Thanks

```
Year      Region  Emission      Loss
1961      Europe 215531.50 184614.45
1961  Indus.Asia  66269.86 100460.35
1961      Lat.Am  66270.42  38745.49
1961 NAfr.WCAsia  23812.97  21466.71
1961 NAm.Oceania 133090.19  77584.59
1961         SSA  53151.44  34586.91
```

Comment: Please provide some more data

Comment: Agree you should provide longer example. Also suggest providing "correct" output from that example.

Comment: Thanks both for the suggestions on how to improve my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq` and `%in%` to `subset` the rows

```
subset(data, year %in% seq(1961, 2011, by =10))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  Just what I was looking for! I then used the {reshape} package to melt and recast into desired format.